# How to retrieve a view as an int in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a view `MyView` that returns a list of IDs from the database and I have to map it to Entity Framework in my solution. However Entity Framework generates me a class `MyView.cs` that has one column

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

I am asking if I can use Entity Framework to retrieve just a list of `int` instead of generating the wrapper class over the `int`.

I am using .Net Framework 4.7

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
List<int> intList = yourContext.MyView.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

That will go through all entries of `MyView` and select out the `Id` value and store those values into a `List<int>` as the end result.